# Cost of systems to connect a 6 MW wind turbine to the grid

Tags: power-grid

Assumptions: The turbine is pretty close to an American (US) grid. National Grid will charge $50,000 to install isolation switches and remote control systems that let the device connect to the grid. The turbine will need electrical systems to convert the power it generates to power that can be used on the grid.

Question: Roughly speaking, how much will the systems to convert turbine power to grid power?

These systems would include HV breakers, power measuring devices, control systems for power output, frequency converters, transformers, and grid connection equipment.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: Does the turbine include frequency control equipment or is that part of what you are costing?

Comment: @winny No, this would be an odd homework question. And if it were, I couldn't imagine what class it would be for.

Comment: @BrianDrummond The frequency control cost is covered by the turbine cost.

Comment: Ask your turbine dealer.

Comment: @pjc50 I tried to do this with GE, but they rejected the student inquiries

Answer (score 1):

Ballpark $2.5/W  for storage (60%) and GTI (40%)
PV costs ~ $1/W

Lookup Huawei GTI's with remote S/W.  best in class..

Comment: I assume GTI = Grid Tied Inverter

Comment: If you are reading about 6MW to grid then yes you will have many GTI's in tandem. with >600V and ~80A fuses with 6 MVA transformer